# How to ajax call from RiotControl Store?

Tags: ajax, riot.js, riotcontrol

I have created APIs with Nodejs/Express.
Let say I can do GET request to `localhost:8080/list` and it returns JSON of my TODO list and I can POST to `localhost:8080/list` to create new to do list.

Then I use Riotjs + Riotcontrol for my Frontend website.
How do I request from todostore.js file?

This is the riotcontrol todostore.js file which I get from riotcontrol demo folder

[Riotcontrol](https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl/)

```
// TodoStore definition.
// Flux stores house application logic and state that relate to a specific domain.
// In this case, a list of todo items.
function TodoStore() {
  riot.observable(this) // Riot provides our event emitter.

  var self = this

  self.todos = [
    { title: 'Task 1', done: false },
    { title: 'Task 2', done: false }
  ]

  // Our store's event handlers / API.
  // This is where we would use AJAX calls to interface with the server.
  // Any number of views can emit actions/events without knowing the specifics of the back-end.
  // This store can easily be swapped for another, while the view components remain untouched.

  self.on('todo_add', function(newTodo) {
    self.todos.push(newTodo)
    self.trigger('todos_changed', self.todos)
  })

  self.on('todo_remove', function() {
    self.todos.pop()
    self.trigger('todos_changed', self.todos)
  })

  self.on('todo_init', function() {
    self.trigger('todos_changed', self.todos)
  })

  // The store emits change events to any listening views, so that they may react and redraw themselves.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your `TodoStore`

```
self.on('todo_init', function() {                                
  // Trigger loading here perhaps, then set loading = false when it's loaded
  //self.trigger('set_loading', {value: true})                  
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/list')                        
              .then(response => response.json())                            
              .then(function (json) {                                       
                  self.todos = json                    
                  self.trigger('todos_changed', self.todos) 
              })                                                            
})
```